# Fixed elements aren't clickable when I quickly scroll to the bottom in iOS Safari 9+

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design, webkit

I've run into a very annoying issue only on iOS Safari 9+ (8.4 is fine) where, once the user quickly scrolls a page resulting in anchor links within fixed elements no longer being clickable due to the appearance and actual click/hit area not lining up with its element until the user scrolls again.

It doesn't happen the same way every time, and can take a few tries to "break" the system. Content must be longer than the viewport for this to work.

[image: iOS 9+ Safari Fixed:Position Scroll Issue Screen Recording]

No workarounds to the problem yet. How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE:** After further testing, the issue only happens with iOS Safari 9 and above, tested on iOS 8 and there is no problem.

**UPDATE 2:** It's now clear that this happens on most websites using `position:fixed;` and even `position:-webkit-sticky;`.  You may want to check yours :)

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</section>

<div class="sticky">
  <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
}

article {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.sticky {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  background: orange;
  text-align:center;

}

.sticky a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

http://codepen.io/toobulo/pen/dGEodo

The issue doesn't happen within Codepen editor, as it's related to mobile Safari's elastic / toolbar size changes. Please export code into own page, or use the following link:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/anonymous/3234ad797dd80e5f8905/raw/ab51c4d8621cfb827f83a33d21940579f8682cde/index.html

Answer (score 6):

This problem is related to the bounce effect in ios and losing the toolbar & the header bar. The only way that i have found to fix this is to do the following:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
}
```

You could do it on a breakpoint as well so it only works for mobile. Hope this helps.

** Added the overflow scrolling.

Comment: While this workaround fixes the issue, it opens a new can of worms for various areas such as javascript calculations- eg:  
`var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); if (scroll >= 10) { // do something }`

Comment: @Joe You should include that as part of the question requirements then

Comment: @ZachSaucier I didn't want to overcrowd the question with brand-new requirements stemming from various suggested fixes, hoping the behavior would be solved in it's simplest form (without JS-related issues), therefore my comment is fitting within this response, no?

Comment: @Joe If the overflow (bounce) is the culprit and it is limited to iOS, then perhaps the [`-webkit-overflow-scrolling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) CSS property may help, [example here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/).

Comment: @RogierSpieker could you please elaborate?  Are you simply suggesting the momentum scrolling once using Andy's method?

Comment: @joe well, I'm not sure if I've interpreted the question correctly, but if you experience the problem _due to the bounce effect_, it may be solved by setting the CSS property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` to the body-element. It will (well, should) disable the elastic/bounce effect. So yes, you should try it to add it to Andy's suggestion (if it does not solve you issue on its own, that is).

Answer (score 0):

I found that [andy jones's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333654/fixed-elements-arent-clickable-when-i-quickly-scroll-to-the-bottom-in-ios-safar#answer-35337262) effectively fixed this problem for me, but it had an unwelcome side effect: momentum scrolling no longer worked. This made scrolling down long pages on an iPad take forever.

Combining andy's answer with [this tidbit from CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/) made my links clickable while also allowing for momentum scrolling:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* must be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I also found that the `width: 100%` style from andy's answer was unnecessary, so I removed that as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can make **.sticky a** link absolute and apply following CSS so the link will be independent to the window/browser.

```
.sticky {
  width: 50px;
}
.sticky a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help since I need Fixed positioning relative to the viewport - not the document height.  With your solution, the div will scroll with a long page.

Comment: Ok, then you can also try calculating (var1) = (viewport hight) and (var2) = (viewport's bottom position in the page) on each scroll using **resize function (of jQuery)** and calculate: (mid_point) = (var2 - (var1)/2). I hope you got it. You can then set your block's position to **mid_point** dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, although it would be nice to solve using Position:Fixed; and no additional JS, I appreciate your help and will try this as a last resort.  :)